# myProgrammingLab "palindrome" challenge and recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, recursion, palindrome

I'm taking an Intro to Programming class and a good chunk of the material is drilled into our heads through myProgrammingLab. I'm having a little trouble with the concept of Recursion... It's sort of been hit or miss for me. This particular problem has me stumped. When I submit my code, it offers me

```
CTest1.cpp: In function 'bool isPalindrome(int*, int)':
CTest1.cpp:9: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
CTest1.cpp:9: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'bool isPalindrome(int*, int)'"
```

as advice, which I can assure you is not very helpful. Lol

I think my main problem is when I get to the actual recursion. I'm aware that something's off, but.. If you could just point me in the right direction, I would very much appreciate it.

A 'array  palindrome' is an array  which, when its elements  are reversed, remains the same (i.e., the elements  of the array  are same when scanned forward or backward)

Write a recursive, bool-valued  function, isPalindrome, that accepts an integer -valued  array , and the number of elements  and returns whether  the array  is a palindrome.

An array  is a palindrome if:
the array  is empty (0 elements ) or contains only one element  (which therefore is the same when reversed), or
the first and last elements  of the array  are the same, and the rest of the array  (i.e., the second through next-to-last elements ) form a palindrome.

My code so far:

```
bool isPalindrome(int arr[], int n){
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (arr[n-1] == isPalindrome(arr[((n-1) - n) +1 ], n))
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have now changed my problem line to

`else if (arr[n-1] == isPalindrome(arr[], n-1))`

Now I get the hint "We think you might want to consider using +." I can't see where adding would apply here. I don't think it's talking about incrementing because it references incrementing as "++" like in code.

I am also given the error message:

CTest1.cpp: In function 'bool isPalindrome(int*, int)':
CTest1.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token

Is the second line giving an error because the brackets are empty in my first argument?

Comment: What do you think `arr[((n - 1) - n) + 1]` is if you require `int arr[]`?

Comment: You are passing an element of an array when the argument wants a whole array.

Answer (score 1):

When you recursively call `isPalindrome` you pass these two arguments

```
isPalindrome(arr[((n-1) - n) +1], n)
```

The second is fine, but the first argument evaluates to

```
arr[index]
```

Which is just indexing a value out of your array, and will evaluate to `int`. Since it is looking for an `int*` or in other words, the address of the element to start at, you can pass

```
&arr[((n-1) - n) +1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler advice is actually very helpful for you in this situation.

```
CTest1.cpp:9: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
```

It is saying that you are giving the function an int, whereas the function is expecting an int*.

```
CTest1.cpp:9: error:   initializing argument 1
```

Is saying that the problem is in argument 1.

Now to your code. See this line:

```
else if (arr[n-1] == isPalindrome(arr[((n-1) - n) +1 ], n))
```

You can see that the first argument you are sending is not an int* (i.e. not the pointer to the array), but an element of the array. You are sending an int as the first argument.

Try to rework your code taking this into account.